# Project raised exception class EAccess Violation in BCB 6.0

Tags: c++builder

My code can compile successfully and run, however when I terminate it, the error message appears occasionally.

```
Project raised exception class EAccess Violation with message 'Access violation at address 0040..... in module `00F.....`. Write of address ..........' Process stopped. Use step or Run to continue.
```

and I also noticed that the error always happens within these three lines of code in turn.

```
 YCB[i][j].R=((65.738*image[i][j].R)+(129.057*image[i][j].G)+(25.064*image[i][j].B))/256+16;
      YCB[i][j].G=((-37.945*image[i][j].R)+(-74.494*image[i][j].G)+(112.439*image[i][j].B))/256+128;  
      YCB[i][j].B=((112.439*image[i][j].R)+(-94.154*image[i][j].G)+(-18.285*image[i][j].B))/256+128;
```

The code is used to transfer `RGB` to `YCbCr`

because my program has a function that records the screen into .avi file, as long as the error appears when I terminate it, the file cannot store perfectly (which means it cannot open by any means of player).

This question troubles me, though sometimes nothing occurs...

I really want to understand what this message means, and how can I solve it when it shows up again.

P.S Seems like it has something to do with  the memory, how can I inspect the memory record in BCB 6.0 ??

Comment: You should turn on CodeGuard. It is a way to detect such bugs.

Comment: you can also break the line into smaller chunks to narrow down where the error is occuring.  Maybe i or j are negative or too large for the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `EAccessViolation` means you are accessing invalid memory. So either:

1. The `YCB` and/or `image` array(s) are invalid.
2. `i` and/or `j` are going out of bounds of the array(s).

You have not shown enough code to demonstrate how and where the arrays are allocation, how and where the arrays are freed, or how `i` and `j` are getting their values.  So there is no way for anyone to diagnose the problem for you.  You will just have to use the debugger and see for yourself what is actually going on with your app's shutdown logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it turns out that I made a mistake about pointer's memory allocation, I solved it anyway. Sorry for seeing this answer after a long time.